# 2.93 Render Window Always on Top

Tags: rendering, windows

I just installed the latest available version 2.93.0 (win). When I press F12 to render, it popups render window, but now render window is always on top! So, I can't switch back to 3D view window (because render window is on top). I just can resize topmost render window and switch between windows (but render window still visible). Maybe there is new settings about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature in 2.93 [check in comment](https://developer.blender.org/rB261fa052ac42)  See also the reference notes for 2.93 ([2.93 UI reference notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.93/User_Interface)).

Child windows are always on top of their parent in Windows in 2.93.